# Unable to use emojis in App: Rejected to submit to AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, emoji

Does anybody know if ALL emojis are property of Apple. I am trying to use a lot of them (around 80) in my app as text but App was rejected.

I asked if there was a list of emojis that I cannot use but got no answer, if you have already been rejected by AppStore submission process you will know that it may be handled by robots, not people.

I would like to know if only food emojis.. or faces are restricted or ALL of them emojis.

Thanks !!

Comment: What was the actual text of the rejection?

Comment: Guideline 5.2.5 - Legal - Intellectual Property


Your app does not comply with the Guidelines for Using Apple's Trademarks and Copyrights. Specifically, your app includes:

- Apple trademark, emojis, imagery - or likeness - in the screenshots and binary.

Comment: @AlanGonzalez check my answer you will surely get some hint out of that

Comment: https://mjtsai.com/blog/2018/01/23/rejected-from-the-app-store-for-emoji-in-screenshot/

Answer (score 0):

I had recently faced the same rejection under 5.2.5. I had also tried using unicode character representation of emojis in code, instead of hard coded emojis directly in strings like ""
But my app was still rejected, this is one of the latest rules added in the guidelines so I am assuming that the apps submitted before this rule was added, might be using all those emojis !

In short - Can't use Apple's emojis in our applications anymore.

Update: You can add [EmojiOne](https://www.emojione.com/) as an alternative to display emojis in your application, but those would be pngs.

Comment: Yes, that was my choice, went to EmojiOne, added png images as emojis and my app still uses emojis ... it is an emoji memory game so it uses tons of emojis ... hopefully, in the future, Apple will consider emojis as another font .. just as if they were Helvetica or Avenir and everybody will be able to use them

Answer (score 0):

I just had a 5-year-old app rejected because I used a couple of emojis to customize buttons.

[emoji for slider and for stepper up and down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn6t9.png)

Answer (score -2):

From your words it looks like apple rejected your application due to you have used content for which they have copyrights & that someone can not use on its own.

Here are some apples rules that can causes the rejections :

> - Any one can not use Apple graphics or Emojis like any of the content which is already created by them & have owns copyrights & its
>     their own assets
> - Any one can not create a similar similar graphics as well as they have trademarks of it & that assets are representing identity of Apple

Regarding your issue :

> - You can not use similar emojis as apple inbuilt apps, features have in their own apps
> - There is no restriction on how or which kind of emojis you needs to show in your app but it must be Unique & not copied from any where

I hope this will help.

Comment: Strange thing here is that I have another app that uses emoji, something like "You did a good job " but they do not have a problem with this ... seems like using a certain amount, don't know probably 20, 40 emojis is a problem ... but a couple of them is not. Thanks Mayur

Comment: @AlanGonzalez no thats not an issue. It depends on reviewer sometimes the reviewers does not pay attention on it & some times its gets highlighted more