# What's the difference between iOS 12 and iOS 13 when it comes to including emoji via its code point

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

Before we start, I'd like to clarify...

- This question isn't about *how* to include emoji on labels. I'm aware that has been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619267/showing-emoji-in-a-uilabel) before. I am able to get the emoji on the label just fine.
- This question isn't about whether we *can/should* include emoji on labels. I am aware of the [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100450/unable-to-use-emojis-in-app-rejected-to-submit-to-appstore) [around](https://blog.emojipedia.org/apples-emoji-crackdown/) [that](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/96853) too. We'll discuss as a team whether we want to proceed with emoji, but it doesn't make me any less curious about the issue below.

With the disclaimers out of the way, our situation is as follows: We have an iOS app that deploys back to iOS 12. In it, we'd like to include the [warning sign](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+26A0) on a `UILabel` to signal certain situations. The text of the label comes from this bit of code (including picture, because pasting emoji doesn't come through):
[image]

This line isn't setting `someLabel.text` directly but it's the relevant bit. I can promise you that surrounding code simply prepends this snippet to other text and slaps it onto a label.

The first character of that literal string at the end of the line is the "warning sign" emoji inserted into the source code via hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and choosing it from the resulting picker. Then we have the unicode code point `\u26A0`.

I get the following when this code runs:
[image]

At this point I'm really curious about...

- What changed between iOS 12.4 and 13.7 such that the *same source code* produces different output? Was the different treatment of unicode code points announced somewhere on some release notes?
- Is one side somehow "more correct"? Does the "yellow-triangle-with-black-exclamation-in-it" symbol and `\u26A0` technically represent different things, iOS 12 mistakenly visualized them as the same, and iOS 13 fixed that issue? Or vice versa; they are actually meant to represent the same thing, iOS 12 did so, and iOS 13 broke something? Or does the concept of correctness not even apply, since they are different representations?
- Is there any code point I can type into my source file (e.g. `\u<something>`) that will render as the yellow-triangle-with-black-exclamation-in-it emoji *consistently* on iOS 12 and later? If so, what is it? If not, is using the actual emoji in my source code the only way to achieve this?

Comment: @matt Interesting... Thanks for pointing that out. Then how come it shows as "yellow thing" when rendered on iOS 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two variants, `26a0fe0f` and `26a0fe0e`. The former is the emoji variant; the latter is the text variant. In iOS 13 you are using both of them. I don't know why it chooses the second one as a fallback in iOS 13 but the first one as a fallback in iOS 12; the iOS 13 behavior seems more correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, but leaving question and answer up in case it helps others.

The crux of the issue is that the "yellow-triangle-with-black-exclamation-in-it" symbol and the "black-bordered-triangle-with-black-exclamation" symbols are *not* the same entity. We see these in the character viewer built into macOS:
[image]
[image]

And sure enough, the representation `\u26A0\uFE0F` renders as "yellow-triangle-with-black-exclamation-in-it" on both iOS versions:
[image]

If `\u26A0` wasn't supposed to be the "yellow-triangle-with-black-exclamation-in-it" emoji, I still can't explain why it renders as such on iOS 12...

Credit actually belongs to user [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt). He had a comment which hinted at these being different, which led me down this path. The comment is no longer there for some reason (got deleted?) so I don't know how to properly attribute.

Comment: U+FE0F is a "variation selector", which alters the appearance of the  preceding character.  For symbols, the variant forces it to be rendered as a colorful glyph rather than a text glyph.  The U+FE0E variation selector forces the preceding character to be rendered as a text, and not colorful.  In your screenshots, you see how the various fonts render it; most use bare text as the default it would seem.  Looks like Apple changed their default in iOS 13. See https://www.unicode.org/Public/7.0.0/ucd/StandardizedVariants.html .